# How to remove column from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am using MS SQL server (2017, Standart Edition-64). I deleted some columns from my DB table, but these columns still appear in table view which is causing me some performance problems. **I need to delete  columns from a view.**

I am aware that there is no DROP COLUMN statement for Views as it is for tables. Also - it seems that ALTER VIEW doesn't offer option to delete columns.

The View has specific dependencies and triggers, so I can't just simply delete and make a new one. Maybe there is some way to recreate view droping unneeded columns, but  preserving all other properties?

Comment: You need to redefine the view (using `alter view`) with the new definition that has only the columns you want.

Comment: A `VIEW` is a pseudo-table defined by a `SELECT` statement. If you don't want to display a column in the `VIEW` you need to remove it from it's definition by not including the column within the (final) `SELECT` clause of the View's definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    create view test001 as
    select name,company from [dbo].test
    
    alter view test001 as
    select name,company,address from [dbo].test
```